A/B Test Proportions when one of the samples has zero responses
Hi everybody I made an experiment about the conversion of customers that had some responses in group A but 0 responses on group B. If I input these values in a two-sample proportions_ztest It gives me a pvalue but can I trust it? I know that behind this test, it uses the pooled variance aproximation of the binomial to a normal distribution and, as a rule of thumb, to use the aproximation to the normal we  need n*p>5 for both samples. If I assume the rule of thumb is correct, I can say the test was inconclusive, or maybe I can turn it in a one-sample test? Any thoughts?

How many units were in your test?  A total of 0 responses makes me think your data are small or there are problems with your instrumentation for measuring the outcomes.

@DemetriPananos, at least for tests of reliability, when you designed your product to "not fail", 0 "outcomes" (i.e. 0 failures) is actually the desired result, and the most common one for reliability tests; it is not at all a sign of problems with the instrumentation.

@jginestet Then OP needs to clarify what it is they intend to do with the test, because if you get 0 events in my world that very well could mean that your instrumentation is broken, especially if you expect the rate to be non-zero.

Indeed, you should not use a z-test when one (or more) of the observed frequencies is 0 (for group B in your case); the sampling distribution of the proportion will not be normal, so the z-test (which is a normal approximation) will not give you a correct result.
Wrt the "rule of thumb" you mention, indeed, it would not be met in your case. Note however that this rule is not universaally accepted/adopted. See. e.g. this Penn State post, where the "threshold" can go from 5, to 15...
However, you can still perform your comparison, by using the Fisher-Irwin exact test (aka Fisher exact; see wikipedia). It makes no assumption of normality, and is indeed the one to use when 1 (or more) of the observed proportions are 0. You can find online calculators for it here, or here (e.g.). And most (all?) statistical software will offer this test.
